# Python Image Uploading with AjaxUpload

Tags: python, pylons, python-imaging-library, image-uploading, ajax-upload

I'm trying to use AjaxUpload with Python: 
http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

I would like to know how to access the uploaded file with Python.  On the web site, it says:

```
* PHP: $_FILES['userfile']
* Rails: params[:userfile]
```

What is the Syntax for Python?

request.params['userfile'] doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance!  Here is my current code (using PIL imported as Image)

```
im = Image.open(request.params['myFile'].file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in django, you can use:

```
request.FILES['file']
```

instead of:

```
request.POST['file']
```

i did not know how to do in pylons...maybe it is the same concept..

Answer (score 1):

```
import cgi

#This will give you the data of the file,
# but won't give you the filename, unfortunately.
# For that you have to do some other trick.
file_data = cgi.FieldStorage.getfirst('file')

#<IGNORE if you're not using mod_python>

#(If you're using mod_python you can also get the Request object
# by passing 'req' to the relevant function in 'index.py', like "def func(req):"
# Then you access it with req.form.getfirst('file') instead. NOTE that the
# first method will work even when using mod_python, but the first FieldStorage
# object called is the only one with relevant data, so if you pass 'req' to the
# function you have to use the method that uses 'req'.)

#</IGNORE>

#Then you can write it to a file like so...
file = open('example_filename.wtvr','w')#'w' is for 'write'
file.write(file_data)
file.close()

#Then access it like so...
file = open('example_filename.wtvr','r')#'r' is for 'read'

#And use file.read() or whatever else to do what you want.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with Pyramid, and I was trying to do the same thing. After some time I came up with this solution.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from cgi import FieldStorage

fs = FieldStorage(fp=request['wsgi.input'], environ=request)
f = StringIO(fs.value)

im = Image.open(f)
```

I'm not sure if it's the "right" one, but it seems to work.